# Utilizar Multi Select a través de una variable php

Tags: php, html

Tengo una variable llamada `$dias = 7;`

Quisiera saber si es posible que de acuerdo a ese valor pueda utilizar un Multi Select para elegir esa cantidad de días que tiene asignada la variable `$dias`.

Ejemplo:

```
<div class="form-group row">
                <label for="dias_solicitar"class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-2 col-form-label">Dias a solicitar </label>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                 <select>
                      <option value="1">1</option>
                      <option value="2">2</option>
                      <option value="2">3</option>
                      <option value="4">4</option>
                      <option value="5">5</option>
                      <option value="6">6</option>
                      <option value="7">7</option>                                
                    </select>
                 </div>
            </div>
```

Que por ejemplo si el valor tiene `$dias = 7;`, me dé solo opción a seleccionar el número 7.

Si tiene el valor `$dias = 10;`, me dé opción a seleccionar el número 10.

Y bueno aparte de esto pondré una opción para que si selecciono 2 dias en el datepicker me deje solo seleccionar 2 dias pero esto ya es otra cosa.

Comment: quieres que te muestre valores del 1 al 7 o del 1 a n-numero dependiendo de ese valor?

Comment: No esta muy claro lo que quieres... Si la variable tiene el valor 7 que solo te de la opción de elegir el 7? Es decir en el select se refleja el valor 7 y el usuario ya no puede elegir otro valor... ??

Comment: Es dependiendo del valor que contenga la variable dias el total de select

Comment: Sigo sin entender lo que quieres... Si no te sirve la respuesta tendrías que explicarte mejor....

Comment: @Juan "_ pondré una opción para que si selecciono 2 dias_" <-- ¿y qué valor tendría `$dias` si seleccionó 2 valores?

Comment: @aldanux gracias ya me respondieron.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segun tengo entendido a tu prejunta, quires muestrar el cantidad de dias posibles segun tu variable `$dias`. Como vemos en tu ejemplo $dias=7 y existen 7 `option` relacionado, te voy a dejar un ejemplo mediante `PHP`.

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="dias_solicitar"class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-2 col-form-label">Dias a solicitar </label>

    <div class="col-md-2">
       <select>           
          <?php
             //Tu variable.
             $dias=7;

             for ($i=1; $i <=$dias ; $i++) { 
                echo "<option value=" . $i . ">" . $i . "</option>";
             }
          ?>
        </select>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Gracias con tu ayuda pude realizar lo que solicitaba

Comment: Me alegro que te haya solucionado el problema. Un saludo.